# CORS denying connection to socket io

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, cors

I'm trying to use socket io to send and receive data in realtime, but when I run server and open the client page which connects using socket.io-client, I'm getting an error

I installed cors and used it like I've done multiple times before and I tried setting the headers of my response to Allow access from different origin but nothing worked.

this is the error I'm getting:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=ONQYon3' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

this is my server side code

```
require("dotenv").config();

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");

const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const app = express();
const server = require("http").Server(app);
const io = new Server(server);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "*",
  })
);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("a user connected");
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const url = process.env.MONGO_URI;

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await connectDB(url);
    server.listen(port, (req, res) => {
      console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}`);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

start();
```

and all I'm doing on the frontend is using socket.io-client library to connect to the server in a react application like this.

```
import io from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io("http://localhost:5000");
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: if you put them both on the same port you wont have cors issue

Comment: @LawrenceCherone but I don't want to a temporary solution because in the end I will not the serve the client and the server on the same port

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass cors options to the io `Server` constructor itself.

E.g. instead of

```js
const io = new Server(server);
```

you need

```js
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I tried that earlier and it didn't work

Comment: @Mustafa could you please try running the same request as browser does but using curl or Postman? Seeing actual response body and headers can help narrow the search

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem. it was because the client and server were running on different ports and even with cors defined socket.io needs its own cors setting in it in order to work, I changed it to this and it worked.

```
const io = require("socket.io")(5000, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
  },
});
```